# User Defined App.config section

Tags: .net, config, app-config, configuration-files, configurationmanager

I would like to know whether I can have the following XML in my app.config. If yes, how can I achieve this OR anything better than this would help too!

```
<DefaultTestData>
<TestData>
  <DEV>
    <Roles name="Role1">
      <add att1="" att2=""></add>
    </Roles>
    <Roles name="Role2">
      <add att1="" att2=""></add>
    </Roles>
  </DEV>
  <Test>
    <Roles name="Role1">
      <add att1="" att2=""></add>
    </Roles>
    <Roles name="Role2">
      <add att1="" att2=""></add>
    </Roles>
  </Test>
  <Production>
    <Roles name="Role1">
      <add att1="" att2=""></add>
    </Roles>
    <Roles name="Role2">
      <add att1="" att2=""></add>
    </Roles>
  </Production>
</TestData>
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? What framework? Your tags are not very useful. Have you tried it?

Comment: I don't know whether any other programming language has some class called ConfigurationManager except C# and app.config!

Comment: Unless you tag it, it is possible that no-one who is aware that this is C# will see it. I went ahead and did that for you.